# FirebaseException ([cloud_firestore/permission-denied] The caller does not have permission to execute the specified operation

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, exception, google-cloud-firestore

I get this exception using Firebase Firestore. I have tried everything and every possible rule for Firestore but still **does not work**.
What I'm trying to do is, getting a user from a collection and then checking the value of it with Riverpod state manager.

Getting a user from Firestore:

```
      Future<UserModel?> getUserData() async {
      DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> userData =
          await firestore.collection('users').doc(auth.currentUser?.uid).get();
      UserModel? user;
      if (userData.data() != null) {
        user = UserModel.fromMap(userData.data() as Map<String, dynamic>);
      }
      return user;
     }
```

Using a provider to get the value and then returning a screen:

```
      home: ref.watch(userDataAuthProvider).when(
            data: (user) {
              if (user == null) {
                    return const RegisterScreen();
                  } else {
                    return const HomeScreen();
                  }
                },
                error: (err, trace) {
                  return Center(child: Text(err.toString()));
                },
                loading: () => const CircularProgressIndicator(),
              ),
```

Firestore rules:

```
  rules_version = '2';
  service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
   match /{document=**} {
    allow read, write: if request.auth.uid != null;
    }
   }
  }
```

Comment: At first glance your code looks fine. But you haven’t provided enough content to judge what your issue is. Provide whole component wise code and any reproducible steps if possible.
Try these troubleshooting steps to analyze what could gone wrong:
[1]Check if `auth.currentUser?.uid` is not null before making the Firestore call. Do this by `console.log(auth.currentUser?.uid)`

[2]Try running the getUserData() function in a isolated file and console.log the userData and user variables to see if they contain the expected values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open your firebase console and Go to Firebase Datastore and make changes below in Rules.

**Edit Rules and change like this**

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

I Hope this things are solve your issue.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fkivo.png